# Why I get this error?

Tags: php

This is the error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Config::getContent() in
>   /home/addicte1/public_html/panel/index.php on line 9 .

Also if you want to see it with your eyes .

[ http://www.addicted.gazduirejocuri.ro/panel/ ]

*index.php script :*

```
<?php
session_start();
define('panel', true);
spl_autoload_register(functions ($class) {
    include 'inc/' . $class . 'class.php';
});
Config::init()->getContent();
?>
```

Comment: what is `Config` class definition?

Comment: It looks like your Config class is not defined, make sure your $class variable is defined/correct and that your include path is correct. My hunch is that your include path should be something like: 'inc/'.$class.'.class.php'

Comment: Also, what data is returned by `init` function? it should return a object having  `getContent` method.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty informative. `Config::init()` returns a `Config`. `getContent` is tried to be called, however it does not exist, hence the error. You need to check the cause of this issue. `getContent` might be `inexistent`. In this case implement it. It might be `private`. In this case you either need to make it `public` or reach it via another method. Or it might be `static`. In this case you cannot reach it with the instance-level `->` operator and will need to use `Config::getContent()`. To exactly identify your problem you need to show us how this is implemented if at all.